# send message from backend to front on Symfony2 ClankBundle

Tags: sockets, symfony, websocket, websub

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- when the server doing X I want to send a message to user Y.

  as I can see in ClankBundle's documentation I can achieve that in two ways:

  1. make a call from the user side on js.
  2. to make a loop that checks if X happened every Z seconds.

  both of them not really effective as I don't want to check my db every Z seconds I know when X happens and I want to send the message when it happens, I mean.. Symfony2 is events based I'm pretty sure I'm missing something around here.

Comment: If you want to know when x happens you need to have an event listener for that x to happen.

Comment: @NawfalSerrar Thanks, but that's not the question.
The question is how do I send it to the front end via ClankBundle socket.